# Regex: Pattern to match any text followed by specific enclosing format

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find the way to get data from an URL using Regex, the URL is build like this:

```
https://myurl.com/action?AAA={10/17/2018 08:00:00}&BBB={XXX123}&CCC={DATA_DATA}&DDD={29696}&EEE={10/17/2018 08:00:00}&FFF={CCC}&GGG={SOMEINFO}&HHH={7234384}&III={https://www.otherurl.com/Page?utm_source=email&utm_medium=medium}
```

Basically what I expect to get is a List of strings like this:

```
AAA={10/17/2018 08:00:00}&
BBB={XXX123}&
CCC={DATA_DATA}&
DDD={29696}&
EEE={10/17/2018 08:00:00}&
FFF={CCC}&
GGG={SOMEINFO}&
HHH={7234384}&
III={https://www.otherurl.com/Page?utm_source=email&utm_medium=medium}
```

By code I'm removing the first URL part (https://myurl.com/action?) so I can use something like Regex.Split to generate the final list, But can't find an easy way to match the pattern, it should be something like:

> anything={anything}

I've tried using ".*={.*}" but didn't work, also @"/\w+={[]}" without any luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may get these matches using

```
(\w+)={([^{}]*)}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vr7i3x/1).

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `={`  - a `={` substring
- `([^{}]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.

[C# code example](https://ideone.com/ani2Ls):

```
var s = "https://myurl.com/action?\nAAA={10/17/2018 08:00:00}&\nBBB={XXX123}&\nCCC={DATA_DATA}&\nDDD={29696}&\nEEE={10/17/2018 08:00:00}&\nFFF={CCC}&\nGGG={SOMEINFO}&\nHHH={7234384}&\nIII={https://www.otherurl.com/Page?utm_source=email&utm_medium=medium}";
var res = Regex.Matches(s, @"(\w+)={([^{}]*)}")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .ToDictionary(
            m => m.Groups[1].Value,
            m => m.Groups[2].Value);
foreach (var kvp in res)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```

Output:

```
AAA => 10/17/2018 08:00:00
BBB => XXX123
CCC => DATA_DATA
DDD => 29696
EEE => 10/17/2018 08:00:00
FFF => CCC
GGG => SOMEINFO
HHH => 7234384
III => https://www.otherurl.com/Page?utm_source=email&utm_medium=medium
```

Comment: From his example results, it appears you may want to include an optional & character after the } as long as it's the final character. I could be wrong as his anything={anything} doesn't specify this condition however.

Comment: @ReeseDeWind Well, there are ways to make the pattern a bit more generic, like `([^=\n\r]+)={([^{}]*)}`. Let's see if OP has any doubts.

Comment: I tried your C# sample but in my case is not working. I modified my question forming the original URL as a single line (as it is in my scenario), maybe is that?

Comment: @AnonDev It still works, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vr7i3x/2) and [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/ERD0eR).

Comment: Wait, do you mean you just wanted https://ideone.com/nuS60g? `Regex.Matches(s, @"\w+={[^{}]*}&?")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's working, my bad, it was an URL Encoding problem on my side, Thanks!